# terminal mkdir with variable and subfolders

Tags: mkdir, xargs

I have a text file "modules.txt" containing (individual module names):

```
dashboard
editor
images
inspector
loader
navigation
sharing
tags
toolbar
```

I want to create a folder structure for each module like:

```
dashboard/templates
editor/templates
flash/templates
images/templates
```

etc ...

I'm fiddling around in the area of:

```
cat modules.txt | xargs mkdir -p $1/templates
```

But this creates the first level of folders, ignoring the /templates part and giving and error:

```
mkdir: /templates: File exists
```

Which it does not.

I've tried all sort of combinations of:

```
cat modules.txt | xargs mkdir -p $1/{templates}
cat modules.txt | xargs mkdir -p $1{templates}
cat modules.txt | xargs mkdir -p $1/{templates}
cat modules.txt | xargs mkdir -p $1\/{templates}
```

(yes, pretty much guessing here)

I've also tried to add the /templates to each line in the text file, but that makes the whole thing crash.

Any ideas how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this did work when adding /templates to the text file. Must have been to tired (or stupid) when fiddling with this.

```
cat file_containing_folder_structure.txt | xargs mkdir -p
```